# How to create a matrix with12 months of rolling/trailing data in Power BI

Tags: matrix, powerbi, dax, visualization, powerbi-desktop

This is my input file, having months of data.

[image: Input file]

Now I want to create this matrix in the PBIX, with 12 months of trailing data from a date slicer.

That is I will have a date slicer and I want to see the previous 12 months of data from the selected month.

For example, if I select Jan'21 in my slicer I want to have data from Jan'21 to Feb'20.

[image: Output]

I watched some of the videos, but those videos focused on measures or rolling average or rolling total, in my case I want columns.

I have no idea how to implement this in Power BI. Thanks.

EDIT:- The Actual Exp and Actual Min column also have N/A for various months.

[image: Updated Input]

Comment: it does not seem very different after test it, what issue you are facing?

Comment: The above output is static, I am unable to make a rolling 12 months of data in a matrix. I asked my colleague for help, we successfully created a table visual with rolling 12 months but not the matrix. The matrix is working fine without rows in it, as soon as I insert row(Class) it goes blank. Can you help? Also `Actual Exp` and `Actual Min` Columns will also have `N/A` data besides percentage.

Comment: I see, don't it is difficult, let me working on it and see

Comment: Yeah, it is but if you want I can update the post with all the information about this whole report.